# How Do You Install Pi Store?

Tags: pi-store

How Do You Installl Pi Store? These Are The Following Commands In The LXTerminal:`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get pistore`

Pi Store Is A Store For The Raspbian And Raspberry Pi.
You Would Have To Make An Acount First.

Comment: I thought the Pi Store failed several years ago.  Didn't it go bust?

Answer (score 1):

The Pi Store is defunct, as announced on the Foundation site earlier this year:

[PI STORE SHUTDOWN](https://www.raspberrypi.org/pi-store-shutdown/)